# overflow:hidden not working on imagebackground

Tags: css, react-native

```
<ImageBackground
                  source={require('../../assets/frame.png')}
                  style={{
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    height: 50,
                    width: 50
                  }}
                >
                  <Image
                    source={
                      userData && userData?.avatar
                        ? { uri: userData?.avatar }
                        : require('../../assets/avatar.png')
                    }
                    style={{
                      height: '100%',
                      width: '100%'
                    }}
                  />
                </ImageBackground>
```

I'm trying to put the image inside the frame and remove the overflow, how can I achieve that?[image: example]
you can see it's extending past the frame

[image: result]

Comment: hey can you share the same on expo snack? will debug it there

Comment: @GauravRoy https://snack.expo.dev/@faysalbsata/imagebackground please state if you can access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the thing is the frame itself doesnt take the entire space, since its an image, and background image doesnt respect overflow:
[Here is the solution](https://snack.expo.dev/aqfl4r0B3)

Ive just made resizeMode = "contain" and decreased the height relatively of player image.

[image]

Hope it works, feel free for doubts:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Image } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={require('./assets/frame.png')}
        style={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          overflow:'hidden',
          backgroundColor:'yellow'
        }}>
        <Image
          source={require('./assets/1659513190.png')}
          style={{
            height: '90%',
            width: '100%',
            overflow:'hidden',
            marginBottom:10
          }}
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    // justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems:"center",
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  
});
```

[image]

Comment: it's not solved the problem, my inside image is still extending outside the frame

Comment: how should it look like? post the expected ss here

Comment: I just edited the main question to include what's expected

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/IgPtXXgR- updated answer , solution SS is above

Comment: close  enough, not quite what I want at the bottom. Thanks